# Questions about the topology of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

1. What is the largest open subset of $\mathbb{Q}$?

I answered that $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't even have an open subset because of the property that  $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in ${\mathbb{R}}$. So if there doesn't exist an open set, there for sure doesn't exist a largest one.
(I used the $\delta$-definition of open to prove this more formally than what I write here)

2. What is the largest closed subset of $\mathbb{Q}$?

I thought it is $\mathbb{Q}$ because of the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ = empty set and the empty set is by definition open.

3. What is the smallest open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}$?

I thought $\mathbb{R}$. Because $\mathbb{R}$ is open and contains $\mathbb{Q}$.

4. What is the smallest closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}$?

Also $\mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{R}$ = empty set and the empty set is by definition open.

Comment: Every set is open in itself, so $\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$. If you ask what is the largest open set in $\mathbb{R}$ that is contained in $\mathbb{Q}$ then it is the empty set. (so it still exists)

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is the largest open subset of $\Bbb Q$. This is true for any topological space. $\Bbb Q$ is also the largest closed subset of $\Bbb Q$. When you say "open" and "closed" you must specify the topology. Otherwise, I just assume you mean the subspace topology

Comment: How do you prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}?$

Comment: There are a few things here to be careful about. First you need to specify a topology on $\mathbb{Q}$. You are probably using the subspace topology induced by the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Also, you need to think about what "smallest" and "largest" mean in this context. Obviously any open set in this topology is infinite, so you need some better way of talking about the order relation on elements of this topology on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Re 3.: What makes you think there *is* a "smallest" open set of ℝ that contains ℚ ? (Hint: There does not exist such an open set.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The fact that $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ is irrelevant; the subsets $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}-\{0\}$ are also dense in $\Bbb{R}$, and they are open. Also, are you asking about the largest subset of $\Bbb{Q}$ that is open in $\Bbb{R}$, or that is open in $\Bbb{Q}$?
2. Certainly $\Bbb{Q}$ is the largest closed subset of $\Bbb{Q}$, because indeed the empty set is open. Note that this contradicts your own answer to the previous question, where you state that $\Bbb{Q}$ has no open subsets. Note that $\Bbb{Q}$ is not closed in $\Bbb{R}$, however.
3. Again your statements have no relation to the question being asked.
4. Again your statements have no relation to the question being asked. You already answered this question in $(1)$, although this wasn't asked. The fact that $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ means, by definition, that $\Bbb{R}$ is the smallest closed subset containing $\Bbb{Q}$.

I advise you to look up the definitions of:

- Subspace topology.
- Dense.
- Open/Closed.

Also have a look at an introduction to proofs to see how to logically connect several statements to reach a conclusion.

Comment: 1. I am asking about the largest subset of Q
 that is open in $\mathbb{Q}$. I now understand why the fact that  $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in  $\mathbb{R}$ is irrelevant.

Comment: 4. Let me rephrase the question: "What is the smallest closed subset of  $\mathbb{R}$ that contains  $\mathbb{Q}$?"